# log request body string in RestController ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

- the final goal:

**log request body string in RestController's @ExceptionHandler**.

- explanations

By default, when request is invalid json, springboot throws a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, but the message is very generic, and not including specific request body. This makes investigating hard. On the other hand, I can log every request string using Filters, but this way logs will be flooded with too many success ones. I only want to log the request when it is invalid. What I really want is in `@ExceptionHandler` I'll get that string(previously got somewhere) and log as ERROR.

To illustrate the problem, I created a [demo project](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/sping-filter-order) in github.

- the controller:

```java
@RestController
public class GreetController {
    protected static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String greet(@RequestBody final WelcomeMessage msg) {
        // if controller successfully returned (valid request),
        // then don't want any request body logged
        return "Hello " + msg.from;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    public String addStudent(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        // this is what I really want!
        log.error("{the request body string got somewhere, such as Filters }"); 
        return "greeting from @ExceptionHandler";
    }
}
```

- the client

  1. valid request
     `curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080 --data '{"from":"jim","message":"nice to meet you!"}'`
  2. invalid request(invalid json)
     `curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080 --data '{"from":"jim","message""nice to meet you!"}'`

I once tried `HandlerInterceptor` but will get some error like

> 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getInputStream() after
> getReader() has already been called for the current request'.

after some searching [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705023/required-request-body-is-missing-after-making-a-copy-using-httpservletrequestwra) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804205/how-can-i-read-request-body-multiple-times-in-spring-handlermethodargumentresol), I decided to use `Filter` with `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`.

```java
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
        chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, response);
        String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(cachedRequest.getContentAsByteArray(), cachedRequest.getCharacterEncoding());
        log.info(requestBody);
    }
```

This code works well except that the log is after the `RestController`. if I change the order:

```java
        String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(cachedRequest.getReader());
        log.info(requestBody);
        chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, response);
```

Works for invalid request, but when request is valid, got following exception:

> com.example.demo.GreetController         : Required request body is
> missing: public java.lang.String
> com.example.demo.GreetController.greet(com.example.demo.WelcomeMessage)

I also tried `getContentAsByteArray`, `getInputStream` and `getReader` methods since some [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318632/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getreader-has-already-been-called-for-this-re) say the framework checks for specific method call.

Tried `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` as suggested by @M. Deinum.

But all in vain.

Now I'm bit confused. Can anyone explain the executing order of `RestController` and `Filter`, when request is valid and invalid?
Is there any easier way(less code) to achive my ultimate goal? thanks!

I'm using springboot 2.6.3, jdk11.

Comment: Ditch your filter and use one of the filters provided by Spring. The `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` comes to mind for that.

Comment: thanks, i just tried `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` but still not working. 1. by default `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` logs the request body **after** the `RestController`. 2. by default `beforeRequest` only prints `Before request [POST /]` and no body string. 3. i tried overriding `beforeRequest` method and get the request, but same issue 'Required request body is missing'. github update with this trial.

Comment: Your description actually states that you want to log it after the method call, as you only want to log invalid requests by an exception handler (which is invoked after a method or while an exception during execution happens). You can just inject/use the `HttpServletRequest` in your exception handler and read the body (you will have to make sure you have a filter that wraps it in a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, check if the request is an instance and use the `getContentAsByteArray` to get the content that has been read. So you only need a filter for the wrapping nothing more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a filter that wraps your request in a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` (nothing more nothing less).
2. Use the `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter in your exception handling method as an argument
3. Check if instance of `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`
4. Use the `getContentAsByteArray` to get the content.

Something like this.

```java
public class CachingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

protected abstract void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

  filterChain.doFilter(new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request), new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response));
}
```

**NOTE:** I wrapped the response as well, just in case you wanted that as well.

Now in your exception handling method use the `HttpServletRequest` as an argument and use that to your advantage.

```java
@ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
public String addStudent(HttpMessageNotReadableException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
  if (req instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) req;
    log.error(new String(wrapper.getContentAsByteArray()));
  }
  return "greeting from @ExceptionHandler";
}
```

It could be that multiple filters add a wrapper to the `HttpServletRequest` so you might need to iterate over those wrappers, you could also use this

```java
private Optional<ContentCachingRequestWrapper> findWrapper(ServletRequest req) {
    ServletRequest reqToUse = req;
    while (reqToUse instanceof ServletRequestWrapper) {
        if (reqToUse instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
            return Optional.of((ContentCachingRequestWrapper) reqToUse);
        }
        reqToUse = ((ServletRequestWrapper) reqToUse).getRequest();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Your exception handler would then look something like this

```java
@ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
public String addStudent(HttpMessageNotReadableException e, HttpServletRequest req) {
  Optional<ContentCachingRequestWrapper) wrapper = findWrapper(req);
  wrapper.ifPresent(it -> log.error(new String(it.getContentAsByteArray())));
 
  return "greeting from @ExceptionHandler";
}
```

But that might depend on your filter order and if there are multiple filters adding wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Following @M.Deinum's comments, I solved and hope useful for others:

1. Add a Filter

```java
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
    chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, response);
  }
}
```

2. Inject the `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` in `ExceptionHandler`

```java
  @ExceptionHandler({ HttpMessageNotReadableException.class })
  public String addStudent(HttpMessageNotReadableException e, ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachedRequest) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    try {
      String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(cachedRequest.getContentAsByteArray(), cachedRequest.getCharacterEncoding());
      log.error(requestBody);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "greeting from @ExceptionHandler";
  }
```